# How to prove that series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3^{-n+(-1)^n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3^{-n+(-1)^n}$$ converges. I'm not sure what I did is enough or is correct though.

My thinking is:

$-1 \le (-1)^n \le 1$ and $  -\infty\le -n \le -1$ so:

$ -\infty\le -n+(-1)^n \le -2 $ which means that $3^{-n+(-1)^n}$ is always less than 1, therefore it's a geometric power series which converges.

Comment: There is no variable $x$ in the series. So I think its not appropriate to call it a power series. Much better, you call it series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty3^{-n+(-1)^n}
&=3^{-1-1}+3^{-2+1}+3^{-3-1}+3^{-4+1}+3^{-5-1}+3^{-6+1}+\cdots\\
&=3^{-2}+3^{-1}+3^{-4}+3^{-3}+3^{-6}+3^{-5}+\cdots
\end{align}$$

is a rearrangement of the absolutely convergent geometric series

$$3^{-1}+3^{-2}+3^{-3}+3^{-4}+3^{-5}+3^{-6}+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(1\over3\right)^k={{1\over3}\over1-{1\over3}}={1\over2}$$

hence also absolutely convergent.

Comment: Is it correct proof to just show that $0 \le n - (-1)^n < \infty$ hence the $\frac{1}{3}$ which the general member of the series will always stay between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @Yos, no, it is, in general, not enough to show that the terms of an infinite series always stay between $0$ and $1$ in order to conclude that the series converges.  Consider, for example, the series $${1\over3}+{1\over3}+{1\over3}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^2}+{1\over3^3}+\cdots+{1\over3^3}+{1\over3^4}+\cdots$$ where you have $3^n$ terms of the form $1\over3^n$.

Comment: Right but what I'm showing is that the series confrom to geometric series definition because the the general member is between $0$ and $1$ and the power is never negative

Comment: @Yos, it's fairly clear that you have a correct intuition regarding how the series in question relates (or "conforms") to the definition of geometric series.  The problem is, you aren't expressing your intuition correctly.  Please don't take that as criticism; it takes time and practice to learn how to communicate mathematical ideas.  Just keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $0\leq 3^{-n+(-1)^n}\leq 3^{-n+1}=b_n$. Since $b_n$ is geometric, it converges. Use the comparison test.

Comment: Surely you meant $3^{-n+1}$, not $3^{-n-1}$.  (See Eff's and Same Shenawy's answers.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you two hints. See if you can solve it with that:

1) An infinite series of non negative terms either converges or diverges to $+\infty$.

2) If the series satisfies 1) and is bounded, then it has to converge. The summand appears to be less than...

You can also use the fact that partial sums are monotone increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a good approach.
Since $$a_n:=3^{-n+(-1)^n}\leq 3^{-n+1} = 3\cdot 3^{-n} =: b_n $$
and since
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$
converges (it's a geometric series), we have by the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) that
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
converges.